# Sunroom construction completion checklist [Toronto]

Tags: pest-control, extension, sunroom

I have a sunroom underway using a contractor with a city reviewed permit. the city does the structural inspection.

Some of the features of the sunroom are:

1. there will be a  skylight and a heat pump
2. gravel below the deck which is probably 1-2 inches thick. hope this will keep out the pests
3. Sunroom approximately 16’ x 10’ more details below
4. Provide 4 season doors and windows
5. Walls will be glass and aluminum
6. Glass enclosure will be on 2 walls only
7. Use 6x6 for post
8. Height of wall = 7 ft Firewall

**what would be my closing checklist items before i sign off ?**

[image: sunroom drawing]

Comment: Are you asking people on the internet to inspect your project?  Your local building department knows better what is proper there. Trust them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, especially since I don't see a question mark (?) anywhere in your "question". Please edit to clarify exactly what you're after.

Comment: If it passes inspection most of the closing checklist will do with workmanship.  Does it look good, is everything have a solid feel, doors and windows are sealed and smooth working/opening, it is left in a clean order.  Depending on the contract keep the last 10/20/30% pay for 30 days in case problems arise.